# Fixing a mistake in "An introduction to invariants and moduli"

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, rt.representation-theory

On page 13 of the book "An introduction to invariants and moduli" of Mukai
http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam033/2002023422.pdf there is a mistake, in the end of the proof of Proposition 1.9.  It seems to me that this proof can not be fixed, without using the notion of Noetherian rings and Hilbert basis theorem.

**The question is:** Can this proof be fixed, without using commutative algebra -- i.e., by the elementary reasoning that Mukai is using there?

I reproduce here the proof from the book for completeness. $S$ is the ring of polynomials, $G$ a group, $S^G$ is the ring of invariants

**Proposition.** If $S^G$ is generated by homogeneous polynomials $f_1,...,f_r$
of degrees $d_1,...,d_r$, then the Hilbert series of $S^G$ is the power
series expansion at $t=0$ of a rational function
$$P(t)=\frac{F(t)}{(1-t^{d_1})...(1-t^{d_r})}$$
for some $F(t)\in \mathbb Z[t]$.

**Proof**.  We use induction on $r$, observing that when $r=1$, the ring $S^G$ is just $\mathbb C[f_1]$ with the Hilbert series $$P(t)=1+t^{d_1}+t^{2d_1}+...=\frac{1}{1-t^{d_1}}.$$
For $r>1$ consider the injective complex linear map $S^G\to S^G$ defined by $h\to f_rh$. Denote the image by $R\subset S^G$ and consider the Hilbert series for the graded rings $R$ and $S^G/R$. Since $R$ and $S^G/R$ are generated by homogeneous elements, we have
$$P_{S^G}(t)=P_{R}(t)+P_{S^G/R}(t).$$
On the other hand, $dim(S^G\cap S_d)=dim(R\cap S_{d+d_r})$, so that $P_R(t)=t^{d_r}P_{S^G}(t)$, and hence
$$P_{S^G}(t)=\frac{P_{S^G/R}(t)}{1-t^{d_r}}.$$
But $S^G/R$ is isomorphic to the subring of $S$ generated by the polynomials $f_1,...,f_{r-1}$, and hence by the induction hypothesis $P_{S^G/R}(t)=F(t)/(1-t^{d_1})...(1-t^{d_{r-1}})$ for some $F(t)\in \mathbb Z[t]$...

**Mistake**: It is not true that $S^G/R$ is isomorphic to the subring of $S$ generated by polynomials $f_1,...,f_{r-1}$. For example consider $\mathbb C^2$ with action $(x,y)\to (-x,-y)$. Then let $f_1=x^2$, $f_2=y^2$, $f_3=xy$.

**Motiviation of this question**. Of course this proposition is a partial case of Hilbert-Serre theorem, proven for example at the end of Atiyah-Macdonald. But the point of the introduction in the above book is that one does not use any result of commutative algebra.

Comment: *Attiyah-McDonalds* is a very funny typo.

Comment: Thanks! That maid me laugh too! But I'll change it nevertheless :)


Comment: @aglearner: *Maconald* is less funny, but still a typo!

Comment: I've heard many people complain about frequent errors in Mukai's book. 

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to the question, I just decided to give for completeness a standard proof of the above statement that uses (a version of) Hilbert-Serre theorem. In this proof we need to use Hilbert basis theorem.  In the above statement $S^G$ is clearly a *finitely generated graded module* over the ring of polynomials $\mathbb C[x_1,...,x_r]$, so it is sufficient to prove:

**Theorem (Hilbert, Serre).** Suppose that $S=\sum ^{\infty}_{j=0}S_j$ is a commutative graded ring with $A_0=\mathbb C$, finitely generated over $\mathbb C$ by homogeneous elements $x_1,...,x_r$ in positive degrees $d_1,...,d_r$. Suppose that 
$M=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} M_j$ is a finitely generated graded $S$-module (i.e., we have $S_iS_j\subset S_{i+j}$ and $S_iM_j\subset M_{i+j}$).
Then the Hilbert series $P(M,t)$ is of the form 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}dim(M_j)t^j=P(M,t)=\frac{F(t)}{\Pi_{j=1}^r(1-t^{d_j})},
\;\; F(t)\in \mathbb Z[t].$$

**Proof.**
We work by induction on $r$. If $r=0$ then $P(M,t)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, so suppose $r>0$. Denote by $M'$ and $M''$ the kernel and cokernel of the multiplication by $x_r$, we have an exact sequence for each $j$
$$0\to M'_j\to M_j \to^{x_r}M_{j+d_r}\to M''_{j+d_r}\to 0.$$ 
Now $M'$ and $M''$ are finitely generated graded modules for $K[x_1,...,x_{r-1}]$, and so by induction their Hilbert series have the given form. From the above exact sequence we have 
$$t^{d_r}P(M',t)-t^{d_r}P(M,t)+P(M,t)-P(M'',t)=0.$$
Thus 
$$P(M,t)=\frac{P(M'',t)-t^{d_r}P(M',t)}{1-t^{d_r}}$$
has the given form.

**Where did we use Hilbert basis theorem?** We use it when we say that $M'$ is finitely generated.